# Java: getting a object from a Hashmap by key

Tags: java, hashmap

I try to refresh my Java skills. But now I stuck at a hashmap. I don't get the right object back. Here is my example code:

```
public class Sample {

    private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> peaks = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    private final String name;

    public Sample(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.peaks = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> getPeaks() {
        return peaks;}

    public static void addPeak(String peakName, String value) {
        Map<String, String> peak = new HashMap<String, String>();
        peak.put("value", value);
        peaks.put(peakName, peak);
    }
}

public class Main {
    static Map<Integer, Sample> sample = new HashMap<Integer, Sample>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sam = new Sample("Test1");
        sample.put(1, sam);
        sample.get(1).addPeak("A", "1");

        sam = new Sample("Test2");
        sample.put(2, sam);
        sample.get(2).addPeak("B", "123");

        System.out.println(sample.get(1).getPeaks().toString());    
        System.out.println(sample.get(2).getPeaks().toString());    
        System.out.println(sample.get(4).getPeaks().toString());    
    }
}
```

EVERYTIME THE OUTPUT IS: {B={value=123}}

I don't know which part is wrong. Did I miss something?

Comment: what are you getting? please paste your output.

Comment: @freak It's there, buried. Joko, please post the output as a separate block instead of hiding it inside a comment.

Comment: o just see :D @chrylis

Comment: If I only remove static I get much more errors (but this is another topic then). I will read about static...

Comment: "sample.get(4).getPeaks()" would throw an NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map is static :

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> peaks = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

Hence, every call to `Sample.getPeaks()` points to the same Map.

```
//getPeaks() returns the same map in both cases.
// In other words : sample.get(1).getPeaks() == sample.get(2).getPeaks()
System.out.println(sample.get(1).getPeaks().toString());    
System.out.println(sample.get(2).getPeaks().toString());

// This is equivalent to
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myStaticMap = Sample.getPeaks();
System.out.println(myStaticMap.toString());    
System.out.println(myStaticMap.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods `getPeaks` and `addPeaks` as well as the map `peaks` are static! That means they only exist once (per class), not once per instance of Sample.

So everytime you create a new `Sample` instance, you're overwriting the static field `peaks` in the constructor! Remove the `static` keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were trying to learn how to use nested Maps, but for this implementation, couldn't you simply create a `Map<String, String>`? The reason I'm asking is because in `addPeak` you've made a call to `peak.put("value", value)`, with the hardcoded string "value", which may be unnecessary. Here's some code which may satisfy what you're interested in:

```
public class WhyMapOfMap {

    // Simpler map
    private Map<String, String> peaks;
    private String name;

    public WhyMapOfMap(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        peaks = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPeaks() {
        return peaks;
    }

    public void addPeak(String peakName, String value) {
        peaks.put(peakName, value);
    }
}
```

Then you may access the map normally `sample.get(key).getPeaks()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe there is an easier way to do so. But in my complete sourcecode I save more the than only 'value'.

Comment: Ah I understand. I sometimes find it difficult to model the data I need into standard collections. In those cases I'll favor an approach of object composition. A guiding principles I look to is "smart data and dumb algorithms". Good luck!